# fetch() does not send request (CSP issue)

Tags: javascript, flask, content-security-policy

I have a Jenkins job which creates a webpage (as an artifact) and it sends a POST to a flask app.

I have already tried adding all sorts of CSP and even allowing all of them, but it's as if it's being ignored by the browser. I tried it through my own profile in my browser (and not my work profile) and it did work, and it does not work for other people as well.

The request:

```
....

  function getNamespaces(cls) {
    const data = {
      cluster: cls,
      username: "${CRED_USERNAME}",
      password: "${CRED_PASSWORD}",
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'unsafe-inline' *; connect-src 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' *;"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    return fetch('http://ilde97192.eaas.mycompany.com:5000/getNamespacesByCluster', requestOptions)
      .then(response => { ......
```

I tried adding this as well:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' *; connect-src 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' *;">
```

Flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/getNamespacesByCluster", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def getNamespacesByCluster():
    data = request.get_json()
    cluster = data['cluster']
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    namespacesOutput = f"""
      login=$(oc login "api.{cluster}.ocpd.corp.mycompany.com:6443" -u={username} -p={password} --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true) && echo "[SUCCESS] Cluster connection established." || (echo "[ERROR] Cluster connection failed."; exit 1 > /dev/null; )
      pods=$(oc get pods --all-namespaces -l couchbase_node | awk {{'print $1'}} | awk 'NR>1') && echo "[SUCCESS] Namespaces retrieved successfully." || (echo "[ERROR] Failed to fetch namespaces."; exit 1 > /dev/null; )
      echo $pods
    """
    
    def generate_output():
        with app.app_context():
            command = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", namespacesOutput], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            for line in iter(command.stdout.readline, b''):
                yield line.rstrip() + b'\n'

    namespaces = generate_output()
    response = Response(stream_with_context(namespaces), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    return response
```

The error:

> BuildReport.html:664  Refused to connect to
> 'http://ilde97192.eaas.mycompany.com:5000/getNamespacesByCluster' because
> it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set,
> so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Does the server send a CSP header?

Comment: It's in the response for the request for the index file.

Comment: Your browser sends a request for the index file and it receives a response with the HTML code. This response has headers. Is there a CSP header?

Comment: I see it now. There is a CSP header but it's a different one: Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self' ; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;

Comment: I assume the header has priority over the meta tag.

Comment: Thanks! what would you suggest to do in this case?

Comment: I prefer to use same origin with a reverse proxy (also no CORS). Otherwise you have to change the policy.

Comment: I have the same header in my own profile in my browser and it works for some reason, but does not work in my work profile, strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple CSPs defined. Adding another policy can only make the total enforced policy stricter as everything has to pass all policies. You will need to identify how and where the existing policy is set and remove/modify it. In most cases you should only set one policy.